# how to know if facebook login had been authorized before?

Tags: facebook, flutter

I'm trying to use facebook login api and the problem is when i login using facebook its create a new record in the database using the same id , how to check if the user is already is authenticated with facebook

Comment: Hi, please elaborate what is the problem you are facing, what have you tried already and what is your expectation. Spend some time to design the question and try to add `code samples` you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Save the facebook ID on database on login and when you get the facebook ID of user again check if already exists on database

Comment: facebook don't provide any way to check ?

Comment: @IzzaldeenRadaideh what would this have to do with Facebook? Handling _your_ database is _your_ responsibility.

Comment: Unfortunately not @IzzaldeenRadaideh